# Transformation of XML tree to flat text using SQL Server 2008 XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, recursive-query, xquery-sql

I have some XML data representing a mathematical expression tree and want to convert this to a flat math formula. Sounds simple, but the XQuery restrictions in SQL Server currently stopped me from succeeding (no recursive functions, problems with "heterogeneous" results etc.).

The expression can be of an arbitrary nesting depth. Here's a sample (the data is in a xml column of a table later on, but that's good enough for testing here):

```
DECLARE @expr xml;
SET @expr = '<expression aggregator="+">
  <indicator>122F277B-A241-7944-BC38-3BB5E8B213AF</indicator>
  <indicator>7DD46849-2193-EB41-8BAB-CE0C45255249</indicator>
  <expression aggregator="*">
    <expression aggregator="/">
      <indicator>122F277B-A241-7944-BC38-3BB5E8B213AF</indicator>
      <indicator>27F3156D-FDA7-1E44-B545-7F27A48D9838</indicator>
    </expression>
    <indicator>ADFCEF34-9877-DE4E-8A00-13576437D82B</indicator>
    <value>12</value>
  </expression>
  <expression aggregator="-">
    <indicator>ADFCEF34-9877-DE4E-8A00-13576437D82B</indicator>
    <indicator>75896474-C197-1C44-8EAA-8FE9D0AB2663</indicator>
  </expression>
  <indicator>27F3156D-FDA7-1E44-B545-7F27A48D9838</indicator>
</expression>';
```

The required result would be (whitespace is insignificant):

```
(
  [122F277B-A241-7944-BC38-3BB5E8B213AF] +
  [7DD46849-2193-EB41-8BAB-CE0C45255249] +
  (
    (
      [122F277B-A241-7944-BC38-3BB5E8B213AF] /
      [27F3156D-FDA7-1E44-B545-7F27A48D9838]
    ) *
    [ADFCEF34-9877-DE4E-8A00-13576437D82B] *
    12
  ) +
  (
    [ADFCEF34-9877-DE4E-8A00-13576437D82B] -
    [75896474-C197-1C44-8EAA-8FE9D0AB2663]
  ) +
  [27F3156D-FDA7-1E44-B545-7F27A48D9838]
)
```

Does someone master XQuery in SQL Server 2008 (R2) well enough to perform this transformation?

Comment: You can't process a tree with undefined deph without general recursion. That's why this XQuery engine has its own tag...

Comment: @Alejandro, sorry didn't catch this tag, Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty but it seems to work. A recursive UDF.

```
create function GetExpression(@expr xml) returns varchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @max int
  declare @i int = 1
  declare @nodetype varchar(50)
  declare @aggregator char(1)
  declare @res varchar(max) = '('
  declare @value varchar(36)
  declare @SubExpr xml

  select @max=count(*)
  from @expr.nodes('/expression/*') as n(e)

  select @aggregator = n.e.value('@aggregator', 'char(1)')
  from @expr.nodes('expression') as n(e)

  while @i <= @max
  begin
    select
      @nodetype = x.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(36)'),
      @value = x.value('.', 'varchar(36)'),
      @SubExpr = x.query('.')
    from @expr.nodes('/expression/*[position()=sql:variable("@i")]') e(x)

    if @nodetype = 'indicator'
      set @res = @res + '[' + @value + ']'
    else
    if @nodetype = 'expression'
      set @res = @res + dbo.GetExpression(@SubExpr)
    else  
    if @nodetype = 'value'
      set @res = @res + @value

    if @i < @max
      set @res = @res + @aggregator

    set @i = @i + 1        
  end

  set @res = @res + ')'

 return @res
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - not very pretty indeed, but I guess the pretty variants don't work because of the SQL Server XQuery limitations... ;) I'll try it out with my test cases (from reading the code I think that it will work fine).

Answer (score 1):

Mikael, you got me on the right track, here's my final solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetExpression (@expr xml)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN STUFF(
    (   SELECT a.x.value('.', 'char'), CASE 
            WHEN v.x.exist('self::expression')=1 THEN '('+dbo.GetExpression(v.x.query('.'))+')' 
            WHEN v.x.exist('self::indicator')=1 THEN '['+REPLACE(v.x.value('.', 'varchar(35)'), '-', '')+']' 
            ELSE v.x.value('.', 'varchar(20)') 
        END
        FROM @expr.nodes('expression/@aggregator') a(x)
        CROSS APPLY @expr.nodes('expression/*') v(x) 
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 
    1, 1, '');
END
```

Comment: Much nicer :). It should also be possible with a recursive CTE but I think you have to use the old `openxml` and use `@mp:id` and `@mp:parentid` to build the hierarchy. I don't know if there are any equivalent functions when using the XML data type.

Comment: Yeah, I also though about doing one with a CTE which always converts the expressions without nested expressions to the textual representation until there aren't any tags in it anymore, but it didn't really work either. I think the UDF is a good compromise (and maybe even the more efficient one).